# New String Functions Not Listing in Web Api Help Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My controller function,

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public string AgencyLogin(string username, string password)
{
    string savedPassword = "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    AGENCYBL agencybl = new AGENCYBL();
    savedPassword = Common.generateSecurePasswordHash(password);
    dt = agencybl.SelectAgencyLoginbyUname(username, savedPassword);

    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        return "Logged In";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Not Logged In";
    }
}
```

And my route ,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }  
    );
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

But this function is not listing in web api help page

Comment: I think you should use Attribute Routing. like [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]. For more info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: i have enabled attribute routing.Still not listing

Comment: Put this attribute [Route("your/route/to/api")] top of your action method.

Comment: no,still api not listing and error is showing for

Comment: localhost:58028/api/Agency/Login?username=johndoe&password=doe

Answer (score 0):

Your action is not a verb so you need to make new route like ASP.net MVC route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }  
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }  
);
```

And use URL like

```
ControllerName/AgencyLogin?username=name&password=pass
```